# Cisco PIX SNMP enabled or not?

Tags: firewalls, cisco, cisco-ios

On a Cisco PIX firewall, I wanted to check if SNMP is enabled:

> pix# sh snmp-server
>
> no snmp-server location
>
> no snmp-server contact
>
> snmp-server community public
>
> no snmp-server enable traps

Is SNMP enabled on this device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. The default configuration for the snmp server is enabled. If you do a `sh run all | i snmp` you should see a `snmp-server enable` line in your configuration. However if you'd like to actually use the snmp server you'll need to add a `snmp-server host x.x.x.x` command to the config.

Comment: Ok, so does the current configuration endanger my firewall? ie can someone get the suprvision data out of it using the default "public" community string?

Comment: And in the configuration, there is no "snmp-server enable" :/

Comment: It should show up if you do a show run all. I could be wrong. Either way, if you're not using the snmp features of the firewall you should do a `no snmp-server enable` and you should always remove the public community string with a `no snmp-server community public`
It's not currently a security risk but these are best practices for locking down an ASA.